# Best practices for sanitizing Unicode input

Tags: unicode, user-input

I'm working on a web application at the moment (using Ruby) that I would ultimately like to be usable by people from anywhere in the world.  With that in mind, support for non-ASCII characters is essential.  However, I don't want the database to be full of "noise" characters in fields such as *username* etc.

Are there any accepted best practices for dealing with Unicode input under these circumstances without alienating users?  Any thoughts on dealing with homographs in usernames to make impersonation harder?

Some of my thoughts so far -

- normalizing text before storing or using it in queries
- filtering non-printable characters
- limiting the number of sequential combining diacritics allowed in input

Any further thoughts, or am I making unnecessary work for myself?

Thanks.

Comment: Honestly, I think you're not only making more work for yourself, you're undermining your stated purpose. If you want your app to support international use, it ought to accept international usernames, passwords, what-have-you. Worse things have happened to databases than to have Arabic characters in a field.

Comment: The goal is to have people be able to register with Arabic/Japanese/Hangul/Devanagari/Klingon/whathaveyou usernames, but to minimize the risks from things such as homograph impersonation if possible.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3454.txt will tell you what you should be doing, which is to say worrying about normalization and security issues.

Comment: Thanks.  Am I right in understanding that LibIDN provides an implementation of RFC 3454 and that this is what I should be using?